# Como leer un codigo QR que esta en formatobyte[] en xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, qrcode

En xamarin.forms tengo una funcionalidad para tomar una foto y esta foto mediante Google Cloude Vision API leo el texto de ella, pero antes de hacer esto quiero que primero hacer la funionalidad que lea la foto primeramente como si fuera un codigo QR o un codigo debarras y obtener el texto de ellos antes de usar Google.

En este momento me encuentro intentando con ZXing.Net.Mobile y ZXing.Net.mobile.Forms que ya tiene la funcionalidad basica para abrir la camara y abrir una paguina de su biblioteca y detecta el codigo y lo lee perfectamente, pero yo no busco que se habra de nuevo una especie de camara ya que ya tengo yo la foto en formato byte[], he visto en google que esta es una forma:

```
            var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();
        var luminanceSource = new RGBLuminanceSource(imgByte, width: 1, height: 1);

        var result = barcodeReader.Decode(luminanceSource);

        if (result != null)
        {
            textoImage = result.Text;
        }

        var textQR = textoImage.ToString();
```

He intentado tomando una foto al QR en incluso un archivo del celular que es una imagen de un codigo QR y codigo de barras que son de buena calidad pero me lee (null).
Alguien pudiera ayudarme o si pudiera utilizar otra libreria.